# passing initalizer list to class constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
  T *ptr;
  int numElem; //-1 if an element. >=0 if an array  
public:
  SmartPointer(T pNum);
  SmartPointer();
  SmartPointer(T *pArray, int pSize);
  ~SmartPointer();
  SmartPointer(std::initializer_list<T> nums, int pSize); //ERROR HERE (line 33)
  T getValue() const;
  T getValue(int index) const;
  void setValue(T pNum);
  void setValue(T pNum, int index);
  int getNumElem() const;
  SmartPointer<T> operator+ (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
  SmartPointer<T> operator- (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
  SmartPointer<T> operator* (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
};

template <class T>
SmartPointer<T>::SmartPointer(std::initializer_list<T> nums, int pSize) //line (45)
{
  ptr = new T[pSize];
  std::initializer_list<T>::iterator it;
  int i = 0;
  for (it = nums.begin() ; it != nums.end() ; ++it)
  {
    ptr[i] = *it;
    i++;
  }
}

(The rest of the code...)
```

I am trying to implement a simple smartpointer, and if I try to compile the code I get two errors:

1) line 33: expected ')' before '<' token

2) line 45: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

But I can't determine the cause of those errors. What I want is that I want to pass intializer_list to constructor so that it dynamically allocates memory internally (inside the class) as follows:

```
SmartPointer<int> test({1,2,3},3)
//do something with test
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Post an MCVE and tell us which compiler you are using with which flags. By the way, you are missing a  `typename` on the line where you declare `it`.

Comment: Include `<initializer_list>` and make sure you're compiling with -std=c++11 or later? (or the corresponding flag for your compiler)

Comment: Yea it was my compiler. Thanks